# How do I create a filter to hide the One Click Accessibility plugin button in WordPress?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, filters, accessibility

I would like to **add a filter to hide** the [One Click Accessibility](https://wordpress.org/plugins/pojo-accessibility/) plugin button, but I want to hide it on several specific pages and [WooCommerce](https://woocommerce.com/) pages.

I just want to show it on a [custom post type](https://wordpress.org/) custom.

The plugin I use to add custom filters is [Code Snippets](https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/).

Comment: Please be aware that 'accessibility' plugins can cause more problems than they solve: https://www.nytimes.com/2022/07/13/technology/ai-web-accessibility.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get current page url and simply apply display none css on button based on current page inside wp_footer action for woocommerce pages you can use predefined functions like is_cart(),is_checkout()..(see code)
just put below code inside your child theme functions.php file

```
function hide_oneclick_toolbar()
{
    if(is_cart() || is_checkout())
    {
    ?>
    <style>#pojo-a11y-toolbar{display:none!important;}</style>
    <?php
    }
}
add_action('wp_footer','hide_oneclick_toolbar');
**hide by specific url**
function hide_oneclick_toolbar()
{
    global $wp;
    $current_url = home_url($wp->request );                                                               //current page url
    $urls_to_hide = array(get_site_url().'/jet/test',get_site_url().'/cart',get_site_url().'/checkout'); // array of urls on which you want to hide toolbar
    if(in_array($current_url, $urls_to_hide))
    {
    ?>
    <style>#pojo-a11y-toolbar{display:none!important;}</style>
    <?php
    }
    else
    {
    ?>
    <style>#pojo-a11y-toolbar{display:block!important;}</style>
    <?php
    }
}
add_action('wp_footer','hide_oneclick_toolbar');
```

Comment: But how do I tell it to literally hide in almost everything but the custom post type that I create with jetEngine?

Because I read the code and it says that it is hidden in the cart or the cart page and the checkout page.

In if it is possible to put the url of the pages that I want to affect with the hiding?

Comment: Maybe I understood that only to WooCommerce pages, but I meant the part of pages, home page, contact page, about us.

Additional hide from WooCommerce pages such as simple products, cart and checkout.

I want to only show that accessibility tool only in a custom post type where there is custom post reading.

I apologize if my message was not very clear.

Comment: @AndersonViviel can you provide links of some of the pages created by custom post type with jetEngine?

Comment: meanwhile you can use updated code above to hide toolbar by urls of specific pages.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and for your help, I will try the code you sent me and tell you how it went, I have a doubt, it is directly inside the functions.php or I can use the code snnipets plugin to insert the code, I am not using the child theme, I do not know if the plugin Child Theme Configurator Free from the WordPress repository can create all connections considering that they are premium plugins.... "limitations of the free version" because I was reading the premium version and it adds more settings and more compatibility?

Comment: You can use Child Theme Configurator to generate child theme and than you can put this code in generated child theme's functions.php file, it will work fine, Child Theme Configurator is a free wordpress plugin.[https://wordpress.org/plugins/child-theme-configurator/]

Comment: Dude it worked great, thank you very much, you are very kind.

Comment: its my pleasure,you can mark it as a right answer if it worked for you :)

Comment: Friend I don't know where to find what you are asking for, could you help me I don't know this platform.

Comment: [link](https://prnt.sc/8ClU6X1qe0f5)